# Any functional difference in different method of accessing a char pointer?

Tags: c, char

for some reason the code I am looking at has a lot of something like

`char tmp[4];`

memcpy(&tmp[0],foo_pointer,bar_size)

I would have expected simply

`char tmp[4];`

memcpy(tmp,foo_pointer,bar_size)

Is there some reason I am missing in writing it the first way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're equal.

The former might be clearer even without the definition of `tmp` in sight.

(And just to make this answer complete as to why it is so, here's the interesting bit from a late draft of the standard:)

> (6.3.2.1p3) Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type "array of *type*" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to *type*" that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
>   register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 6):

Passing an array to a function results in the array decaying to a pointer to its first element so both ways of calling this are equivalent

Answer (score 1):

That's just a difference in style. Some people tend to like expressing that the value they pass to the function is a *pointer*, hence they use the `&` (addressof) operator on the first element of the array. However, this is the same as passing the array itself, since arrays can be passed using address only.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent, but the first one will remind the future readers that `tmp` is an array, while the latter might not make such a distinction obvious.

The latter is easier to read if, and only if, one already knows that `tmp` is an array.  Otherwise, it is more likely to mislead one into thinking of `tmp` as something else.  Blame it on having arrays introduced after simple variables, or whatever you like to blame it upon; but, a variable without extra adornment is often seen by novices as a simple type.

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful to notice that writing

```
&tmp[0]
```

is redundant. It is equivalent to

```
&(*(tmp + 0))
```

So it means: take tmp, add 0, get the value pointed by tmp + 0, get the address of the value pointed by tmp + 0. In other words, you are doing useless operations.

Just write "tmp".